# how to achieve optimal display of homepage in Android concerning outfit?

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome, firefox

It seems that homepage http://nosy-x.com is perfect working by display
with firefox and chrome - but only in desktop computers.

Display is not correct in internet explorer and not in Android-Versions of firefox and of chrome. Apparently this is not directly to do with my code, it looks as if code of Android-Browssers with display in firefox and in chrome is different than those for desktop computers(concerning display of homepages).

Can I add for chrome and firefox in Android a general code for correct display ?
How would this look ?!

At present the relationship between browser and graphical file (pixels) is not correct somehow? All browsers have different output in their display concerning outfit of website with its pixels ...

thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what your question is, but to make a website responsive and make it display the way you want on different screens css media queries is a good place to start. Take a look here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp

Comment: have found this here - but the solution in this code there has no effect : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3292140/how-to-make-sure-a-website-is-suitable-for-all-screen-resolutions - the main problem at my site http://nosy-x.com is - to remove the white space on the right side, and in Android the left side is "swallowed". thx for your link :)

Comment: To remove the whitespace you have to change the with of your body. It is now set to be 1600px, and that is larger than most screens. So remove the with of the body (or set it to 100%). Then I can see that you have some banners with position absolute that is preventing the site to be smaller sideways. So If you can use position relative they will move according to eachother. This will mean that you have to change some of the margin-attributes, but then you will be able to shrink the site.

Comment: thx very much - have already tried earlier with "relative" - but then all banners where over each other (like a pile - now I get it... that was with number in px instead of 100% !). Have set in body to 100% instead of number in px. this works better, but still in Android the left side with banner is cut off. and the right side is fixed but looks not good with "weldseam". It looks as if wallpaper has not correct format and should be created new with more heigth than width. Next attempt is then relative with 100%. You saved my month. ;-)

Comment: Good to hear that you are starting to get it! No problem! Just let me know if you need any more help :)